# Rotate and scale ImageBrush

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I can rotate an image by:

```
  RotateTransform aRotateTransform = new RotateTransform();
  aRotateTransform.CenterX = 0.5;
  aRotateTransform.CenterY = 0.5;
  tateTransform.Angle = rotationAngle;

  ImageBrush bgbrush = new ImageBrush();
  bgbrush.RelativeTransform = aRotateTransform;

  ScaleTransform s = new ScaleTransform();
  s.ScaleX = -1; // how to set without overriding the rotation?
  ...
```

How can I scale it in addition? I tried using matrices without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`TransformGroup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.transformgroup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like so:

```
TransformGroup tg = new Transformgroup();
tg.Children.Add(rotateTransform);
tg.Children.Add(scaleTransform);
bgbrush.RelativeTransform = tg;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [CompositeTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.compositetransform%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), it combines translation, rotation and scaling in a single matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness. Using Matrix transformations, you would get the expected result by this:

```
var transform = Matrix.Identity;
transform.RotateAt(rotationAngle, 0.5, 0.5);
transform.Scale(-1, 1);

bgbrush.RelativeTransform = new MatrixTransform(transform);
```

However, I guess that actually you want to keep the image centered, so you might use `ScaleAt` instead of `Scale`:

```
var transform = Matrix.Identity;
transform.RotateAt(rotationAngle, 0.5, 0.5);
transform.ScaleAt(-1, 1, 0.5, 0.5);

bgBrush.RelativeTransform = new MatrixTransform(transform);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to rotate the `Brush` it self and put it into a rectangle later without having to adjust anything else, this worked for me:

```
// Get the image from somewhere...
ib = new ImageBrush(bmp);

// Here I get it from a larger texture picture.
ib.Viewbox = this.GetVBRect(1728, 634);
ib.Transform = new RotateTransform()
{
    CenterX = 0.5,
    CenterY = 0.5,
    Angle = 180,
};
ib.TileMode = TileMode.Tile;
```